# How do I download Spectre in RStudio

Tags: r

I am following directions from https://wiki.centenary.org.au/display/SPECTRE/Install+Spectre+from+Github. I do not know RStudio very well, but I need to work with some data and thus need Spectre. For some reason when I put the requisite code it does not work.

Code:

if(!require('devtools')) {install.packages('devtools')}

library('devtools')
install_github("immunedynamics/spectre")

Output (A lot of nonsense followed by):

- installing *source* package ‘Spectre’ ...
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** data
  *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  Error in library("flowCore") : there is no package called ‘flowCore’
  Error: unable to load R code in package ‘Spectre’
  Execution halted
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘Spectre’
- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Spectre’
  Warning messages:
  1: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘xfun’ had non-zero exit status
  2: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘openxlsx’ had non-zero exit status
  3: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/j7/p3sjp16n6j5c0mk2l4vmn8sw0000gn/T//Rtmpg2qaiD/file185f75fc78b44/Spectre_0.5.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Spectre::package.check()

Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘Spectre’

Comment: Install the flowCore package.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you had issues during installation. We've made a few updates that should solve this particular problem (which will be present in `v0.5.2` and above). Try installing again using the same instructions. I.e.:

```
if(!require('devtools')) {install.packages('devtools')}
devtools::install_github("immunedynamics/spectre")
```

You can also post an issue [here](https://github.com/ImmuneDynamics/Spectre/issues) if you run into any more trouble.

Good luck!

Tom